# found nil while unwrapping an optional value tableView.register(forCellReuseIdentifier)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
tableView.register(StatusOriginalTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StatusTableViewCellIdentifier.OriginalCell.rawValue)
tableView.register(StatusForwardTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StatusTableViewCellIdentifier.ForwardCell.rawValue)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return statuses?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let status = statuses![indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StatusTableViewCellIdentifier.cellID(status: status), for: indexPath) as! StatusTableViewCell
    cell.status = status
    return cell
}
```

I registered two cells in `viewDidLoad`, but I couldn't find out why it gives me the following error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value swift tableView

[image]

```
enum StatusTableViewCellIdentifier: String {
case OriginalCell = "OriginalCell"
case ForwardCell = "ForwardCell"

static func cellID(status: Status) -> String {
    return status.retweeted_status != nil ? ForwardCell.rawValue : OriginalCell.rawValue
}
```

}

class StatusTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var picWidthCons: Constraint?
var picHeightCons: Constraint?
var picTopCons: Constraint?

var status: Status? {
    didSet {
        topView.status = status
        contentLabel.text = status?.text
        pictureView.status = status?.retweeted_status != nil ? status?.retweeted_status : status

        let size = pictureView.calculateImageSize()
        pictureView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(contentLabel)
            picTopCons = make.top.equalTo((size.height) == 0 ? 0 : 10).constraint
            picWidthCons = make.width.equalTo(size.width).constraint
            picHeightCons = make.height.equalTo(size.height).constraint
        }
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupUI()
}

func setupUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(topView)
    contentView.addSubview(contentLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(pictureView)
    contentView.addSubview(footerView)
   }

override func layoutSubviews() {
    topView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.left.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(60)
    }
    contentLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(topView).offset(10)
        make.top.equalTo(topView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
    }

    footerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(pictureView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
        make.left.equalTo(pictureView).offset(10)
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(44)
    }
}
private lazy var topView: StatusTableViewTopView = StatusTableViewTopView()
lazy var contentLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel.createLabel(color: .darkGray, fontSize: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20
        return label
}()
lazy var pictureView: StatusPictureView = StatusPictureView()
lazy var footerView: UIView = UIView()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
class StatusOriginalTableViewCell: StatusTableViewCell {

override func setupUI() {
    super.setupUI()

    pictureView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(picTopCons as! ConstraintRelatableTarget)
        make.left.equalTo(contentLabel)
        make.width.equalTo(picWidthCons as! ConstraintRelatableTarget)
        make.height.equalTo(picHeightCons as! ConstraintRelatableTarget)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should check if `tableView` outlet is set in your xib/storyboard.

Comment: Have you add StatusOriginalTableViewCell in IB -> -identity inspector?
And one more thind you are using storyboard or Xib?

Comment: I did not use nib or storyboard. I write the code in a custom UITableViewController, so I think it may be the cellIdentifiers. But I cannot solve it。

Comment: if you do `let identifier = StatusTableViewCellIdentifier.OriginalCell.rawValue` in the line above your call to `register`, does that work? If you print it out, what does it print out as in the console?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann    It is 'OriginalCell'.  `enum StatusTableViewCellIdentifier: String {
    case OriginalCell = "OriginalCell"
    case ForwardCell = "ForwardCell"
    
    static func cellID(status: Status) -> String {
        return status.retweeted_status != nil ? ForwardCell.rawValue : OriginalCell.rawValue
    }
}
`

Comment: Well now that you know the identifier looks valid, could you edit your question to show how you delcare your `StatusOriginalTableViewCell` in code?  It should start something like `class StatusOriginalTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {`

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I think it maybe use SnapKit in wrong way.

Comment: one last thing... do you still get the same error if you register your custom cells using "`tableView.register(StatusOriginalTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StatusTableViewCellIdentifier.OriginalCell)`"?? (i.e. taking out the `rawValue` part)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes. Yesterday I register cell using 'tableView.register(StatusTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "StatusTableViewCellIdentifier" ', it went well. After that , I register two cells, I get that error. I change it back by using 'tableView.register(StatusTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "StatusTableViewCellIdentifier" ', does not work.

Comment: Your code isn't clearly formatted, but where do you have the register calls?  Have you set a breakpoint and confirmed that the tableview is not nil at that point?

Comment: Hey, guys. I don't know why. I just make changes on pictureView's layout. It's OK now. Thanks.